# Change value on second select and keep values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello I would like to load data options of the 2nd select from mysql when I click on a value of the first selectors.
And keep the JSON data of the last fields selected and keep append function.

I know how to import data from mysql, but I Would like to get Values each time I change the first selectors without changing all second selectors, only the concerned selector.

How it works.
I select a category ( not shown in the code )
the most important:
The select 1 receive all categories of category selected.
The select 2 receive all categories of select 1 subcategory

when the 1first category is changed, the 2nd selector are loaded but don't forget I need to add unlimited fields without changing all 2nd selectors

im using this code: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/kKjhpy0fdnOprFA8PAYx?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<h3>Add Input fields dynamically</h3>



<button ng-click="addSelectItem()">Add select Field</button>

<div ng-repeat="item in selects">
    <select ng-model="item.type"><option ng-repeat='option1 in type' value='{{option1.nomcarac}}' >{{option1.nomcarac}}</option></select>
    <select ng-model="item.brandname" ><option ng-repeat='option1 in valuelist' value='{{option1.nomcarac}}' >{{option1.nomcarac}}</option></select>
    <button ng-click="getValue(item)">get input value</button>
</div>
        


<pre>{{inputs | json}}</pre>
<pre>{{selects | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.inputs = [];
 $scope.selects = [];
 $scope.type = [{nomcarac: "phone"},{nomcarac: "shoes"}]
 $scope.phonelist = [{nomcarac: "apple"},{nomcarac: "motorola 10g"}]
 $scope.valuelist = [{nomcarac: "test"},{nomcarac: "test2"}]
 $scope.shoeslist = [{nomcarac: "jean michel"},{nomcarac: "motorola 10g"}]
 
 
    var count = 1;
    var fieldname;
    $scope.addItem = function(){
     fieldname = "Field " + count;
     $scope.inputs.push({name: fieldname});
      count++;
    }
    
    $scope.addSelectItem = function(){
      fieldname = "Field " + count;
     $scope.selects.push({name: fieldname});
      count++;
    }
    $scope.getValue = function(item){
     alert(item.value);
    }
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ab34HtswE8Ckszw7jdWO?p=preview
is it what you need?

Comment: @Dreamweaver No I just need to load a new options list for the 2ND selector
When you click on the first select, the 2nd select get response from mysql with the first option selected value. but I don't want to change all second selectors. only the concerned selector

Comment: @jean, please take a look at my answer and see if it helps you.

Comment: yes im looking all yours answers, i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to populate options of the second `select` every time, you change the value of the first select in the group. 
If so, you can use [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to accomplish this and store the values list within the corresponding `item` object:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.inputs = [];
  $scope.selects = [];

  $scope.type = [{nomcarac: "phone"}, {nomcarac: "shoes"}];

  $scope.phonelist = [{nomcarac: "apple"}, {nomcarac: "motorola 10g"}];
  $scope.shoeslist = [{nomcarac: "jean michel"}, {nomcarac: "gucci"}];
 
  var count = 1;
  var fieldname;
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    fieldname = "Field " + count;
    $scope.inputs.push({name: fieldname});
    count++;
  };

  $scope.addSelectItem = function(){
    fieldname = "Field " + count;
    $scope.selects.push({name: fieldname});
    count++;
  };

  $scope.getValue = function(item){
    console.log(item);
  };

  $scope.getValuesList = function(item) {
    //get actual data from db
    switch (item.type){
      case 'phone': 
        item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope.phonelist);
        break;
      case 'shoes': 
        item.valuelist = angular.copy($scope.shoeslist);
        break;
      default:
        item.valuelist = [];
        break;
    }
  };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <h3>Add Input fields dynamically</h3>

  <button ng-click="addSelectItem()">Add select Field</button>

  <div ng-repeat="item in selects">
  
      <select ng-model="item.type" ng-change='getValuesList(item)'>
        <option ng-repeat='option in type' value='{{::option.nomcarac}}' >{{::option.nomcarac}}</option>
      </select>
      
      <select ng-model="item.brandname">
        <option ng-repeat='option in item.valuelist' value='{{::option.nomcarac}}' >{{::option.nomcarac}}</option>
      </select>
      
      <button ng-click="getValue(item)">get input value</button>
  </div>

  <pre>{{inputs | json}}</pre>
  <pre>{{selects | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: my first selects options are generated by a mysql json response.

The first select is dynamic too

Comment: I think you are not far

You select a category. , the subcategory receive data
You select a subcategory. select 1 receive data
You select multiple caracteristics. select 2 receive data from selected select 1, but don't forget data are dynamics, and I need new values on each new 2nd selects

But I want a button to add unlimited caracteristics

Comment: @jean then add `ngChange` handler to the second select and modify the `type` object as needed depending on the value selected. My answer was to give you the idea on how you can populate options dynamically, I don't know all the details of your project.

Comment: Yes I seen you puted static case's but I need dynamic case's, like when I receive a json array, I would create new case whith title from array's values.
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: `case` here was just for example, you can pass the `item.type` to the http call and filter the data on your web server/sql. Or you can fetch all the items and filter them using [array `filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like `item.valuelist = $scope.allItems.filter(function(i){ return i.category === item.type; });`. Hope this helps (anyway I need to understand how the data is fetched to help you more).

Comment: Yes stanislas it's the ways I need but im really novice 
you can see more of my fetching data code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/zR1jtfceUoUD1gA9FIxp?p=preview

I think we are not so far

Comment: Don't use `getElementById("c1").value`, just take the model value of the select and pass it to the `$http` call. Can you please also provide the json sample of the fetched data?

Comment: Hi, you can take a look more informations here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GdM8t74prZke99u1NUQc?p=preview

The fetched response depend where you clic on blue buttons, the last subcategory is used

Comment: I didn't do any change bro, I need the append function. the function is working, I just want create an append button to have new double selects if the user want to add more characteristics, it doesn't work. That's why im looking to change my code to append more selects. looks good actually there is only one double select :'(

Comment: @jean why don't you use `$scope.addItem` and `ng-repeat` markup from the answer?

Comment: cause I didn't understand how to http.post and retrieve data to the item with the $scope.getValuesList = function(item). 
is it like this ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/kEQXLM1w5dnI1OTPOCZt?p=catalogue

Comment: @jean yeah, it should look like the one in the plnkr

Comment: No I sent you the good one, I said shit. so I will try with that

Comment: it works :)! Thanks bro. But I have another problem. can you tell me how to remove the valuelist from JSON array ? Cause I don't need to send it.
https://gyazo.com/2ae8e6f1341e0d618219374aa9fc0b49 . if you don't know, don't worry